# Remove floating label hint text in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

Is there any way to remove floating label (hint) when the user clicks on the text field? When I click on the text field, the hint just automatically moves above the editText but it does not disappear. I want the hint to disappear whenever the user clicks on the text field and enters some texts in it.

Here is the XML code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintStyle"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="false">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_login"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
app:hintEnabled="false"
```

Just add this in your `TextInputLayout`. Despite what the name suggests, it only removes the floating label hint but leaves the EditText hint intact.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same results by calling `setHintEnabled(false)` on the TextInputLayout from your code.

***Pro tip**: You might see your EditText not being aligned properly inside the TextInputLayout if you disable the hint. This is a known issue. A fix for this is to simply add a top padding of 8dp in your EditText. ([Reference](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/180))*

You can refer [the documentation for a better understanding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout#setHintEnabled(boolean))

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `android:hint` and use the **`app:placeholderText`**

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:placeholderText="Password"
        ..>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`**.

Comment: With this approach the placeholder text is not entered vertically within the TextInputLayout?

Answer (score 1):

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
                    app:hintEnabled="false"
      
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintStyle"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false">
    
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/password_login"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                        android:hint="@string/password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

`app:hintEnabled="false"` remove the floating of hint not disabling the hint.

Answer (score 0):

This function can help you (Kotlin)

```
fun hintRemover(textInputLayout: TextInputLayout, textInputEditText: TextInputEditText, text: String) {
    textInputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            textInputLayout.hint = null
        }
        else {
            textInputLayout.hint = text
        }
    }
}
```